# Filter on Onsen UI lazy repeat?

Tags: onsen-ui

Is there a way to apply a search filter on an Onsen UI lazy repeat list ?

If we use for instance `<input ng-model="search.$">`

We can't directly apply `| filter:search` as it is not an ng-repeat.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: you cannot put `| filter:search` on `ons-list` element, which contains `ng-repeat`?

Comment: No I can't. Here is my lazy list (no ng-repeat) :  `<ons-list class="lazy series">
    <ons-list-item class="item" ons-lazy-repeat="SeriesDelegate">
            ....
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the results return by the delegate object:

Simple example:

```
$scope.MyDelegate = {
  configureItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
    itemScope.name = $scope.filteredItems[index].name;
  },
  calculateItemHeight: function(index) {
    return 44;
  },
  countItems: function() {
    return $scope.filteredItems.length;
  }
};
```

In this codepen a large list of countries is filtered in this way:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/VLdGxZ

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much !

Comment: Edit : Works fine on a web page but some issues when used with Monaca.

Comment: Edit edit : set a bigger value for timeout and it works nicely with Monaca.

Comment: @Andreas Argelius How we can set dynamic item height based on the displayed text length ?

Comment: i know its an old thread, but i am getting {{name}} in the output. is there a way to fix this?